# Verify exponential integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{a}{x})^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-a-|a|}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

I need to verify a result $$\int_0^\infty\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2\right]dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-a-|a|}$$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ . What I tried so far is to use residue calculus , but the problem is here $z=0$ would become an essential singularity and it can't be removed by using an inverse sbstitution that is usually made due to the symmetrical $\displaystyle z+\frac{1}{z}$ factor in the integrand . So I have no idea to proceed . Is there any other approach than residue calculus ? If not , what could make the residue approach a bit more easier ? Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4):

For $a \ne 0$ we can substitute $x$ by $|a|/x$, that gives
$$
 F(a) = \int_0^\infty\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2\right]\, dx = |a| \int_0^\infty \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2\right]\frac{1}{x^2}\, dx \, .
$$
And differentiating with respect to $a$ gives
$$
 F'(a) = \int_0^\infty\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2\right]\, \left( -1 - \frac{a}{x^2}\right)dx 
=  (-1 - \operatorname{sign}(a))F(a) \, .
$$
We conclude that $F'(a) = 0$ for $a < 0$, so that $F$ is constant on $(-\infty, 0]$.

For $a > 0$ we get $F'(a) = -2 F(a)$, so that $F(a) = Ce^{-2a}$ for some constant $C$, which can be found by considering the limit $a \to 0$.

(I leave it to you to *justify* the above steps, i.e. show that $F$ is continuous on $\Bbb R$, and can be differentiated under the integral for $a \ne 0$.)

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite the integral as

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2}dx
= \frac12 \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2}dx
= \frac12 e^{-a-|a|} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x-\frac{|a|}{x}\right)^2}dx\\
$$
Note that

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(x-\frac {c^2}x \right) dx
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} 
\overset{x=-c e^{-t}} {f\left(x-\frac {c^2}x \right) dx }+ \int_{0}^{\infty} \overset{x=c e^t}{f\left(x-\frac {c^2}x \right) dx}\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underset{ x=c(e^t-e^{-t})}{f[c(e^t-e^{-t})]c(e^t +e^{-t})} dt =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx
\end{align}
Thus

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2}dx
=\frac12 e^{-a-|a|} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{-a-|a|}$$

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f\left(x-\frac {|a|}x \right) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) dx$ *is* the Cauchy–Schlömilch transformation, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, the algebraic manipulation being  similar to @Quanto's:

$$\Big(x+\frac{a}{x}\Big)^2=x^2 +2a+\frac{a^2}{x^2}=2(a+|a|)+\Big(x-\frac{|a|}{x}\Big)^2$$

Hence

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2}dx=e^{-a-|a|}\int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(x-\frac{|a|}{x}\big)^2}\,dx
$$

Applying the Cauchy-Schlömilch transform,
$$
\int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac12\big(x-\frac{|a|}{x}\big)^2}\,dx =\int^\infty_0e^{-\frac12x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}
$$

Hence
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2}dx = e^{-a-|a|}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

---

The version of the Cauchy-Schlömilch transform I am using is the following:

> ***Lemma:*** Consider the measure  $\mu(dx)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ on $((0,\infty),\mathscr{B}(0,\infty))$. For any $f\in L_1(\mu)$, $a, b>0$,
> $$\int^\infty_0 f(u)\,\mu(du)=a\int^\infty_0f\Big(\big(ax-\frac{b}{x}\big)^2\Big)\,dx=\int^\infty_0f(x^2)\,dx$$

**Proof:** Suppose $f$ is nonnegative and measurable. then
$$I=\int^\infty_0f\Big(\big(ax-\frac{b}{x}\big)^2\Big)\,dx\stackrel{u=b/(ax)}{=}\frac{b}{a}\int^\infty_0 f\Big(\big(au-\frac{b}{u}\big)^2\Big)\frac{du}{u^2}
$$
Hence
$$2I=\int^\infty_0 f\Big(\big(ax-\frac{b}{x}\big)^2\Big)\Big(1+\frac{b}{ax^2}\Big)\,dx\stackrel{y=ax-\frac{b}{x}}{=}\frac1a\int^\infty_{-\infty}f(x^2)\,dx=\frac{2}{a}\int^\infty_0f(x^2)\,dx
$$
whence the statement of the Lemma follows.

Comment: Mittens, very nice, +1. And thank you for providing the Cauchy-Schlömilch transform proof.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-{1 \over 2}\bracks{x + {a \over x}}^{2}}\dd x\,\right\vert_{a\ \in\ \mathbb{R}}}
\\[5mm] = &
\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\pars{-{1 \over 2}\bracks{x + \on{sgn}\pars{a}{\verts{a} \over x}}^{2}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &
\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-{1 \over 2}\verts{a}\bracks{{x \over \root{\verts{a}}} + {\on{sgn}\pars{a}\root{\verts{a}} \over x}}^{2}}\dd x
\\[5mm] = &
\left.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-2\verts{a}\on{f}_{\pm}^{2}\pars{\theta}}\root{a}\expo{\theta}\dd\theta
\right\vert_{\substack{\ds{\on{f}_{+}:\ \cosh} \\[0.25mm] \ds{\on{f}_{-}:\ \sinh}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
2\root{a}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-2a\on{f}_{\pm}^{2}\pars{\theta}}\cosh\pars{\theta}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
2\root{a}\expo{-a - \verts{a}}\times
\\[2mm] & \int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-2a\sinh^{2}\pars{\theta}}\cosh\pars{\theta}\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
2\root{a}\expo{-a - \verts{a}}\int_{0}^{\infty}
\exp\pars{-2a t^{2}}\dd t
\\[5mm] = &
2\root{a}\expo{-a - \verts{a}}{1 \over \root{2a}}{\root{\pi} \over 2} =
\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\root{\pi \over 2}\expo{-a - \verts{a}}} 
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: It follows from
$$
(x+\frac ax)^2 =  (x-\frac ax)^2 + 4a
$$
that
$$
F(a) = \int_0^\infty\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\frac{a}{x}\right)^2\right]\, dx 
$$
satisfies
$$
 F(a) = e^{-2a} F(-a)
$$
for all $a \in \Bbb R$. Therefore it suffices to prove that $F(a) = F(0) = \sqrt{\pi/2}$ for $a < 0$, and that is an immediate consequence of the “Cauchy–Schlömilch transformation”, see Theorem 2.1 in [T. Amdeberhnan, M. L. Glasser, M. C. Jones, V. H. Moll, R. Posey, and D. Varela, "The Cauchy–Schlömilch transformation"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2445.pdf).